# SSRS Report - Graph when exported is compressed into a graphic

Tags: charts, reporting-services, graphics, copy, export

We've built a complex chart in SSRS with a legend and graphs, based off TSQL database. The chart and legend are built part of a table to control placement. The chart shows who is sitting at any particular table at run time.

When the system generates the report it saves it as a PDF or Word document and the user isn't able to copy and paste the content. The system when chart the graphic to word saves it as a graphic encompassing any text in the legend itself.

Is there a way to adjust the report to be able to make the content as a text field. (or have the ability to copy and paste it). For example the legend content to appear copy-able.

[image]

Comment: My terrible idea would be to hide the generated legend and replace it with a text grid the duplicates the info. I have no idea how difficult that would be for positioning and colors and grouping. Probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: ourmandave - that's exactly what I was thinking. This is only way to do it as far as I am aware. If chart colours are controlled by an expression it should not be too hard to replicate that in a table.

Comment: Thinking about it more, you could leave the original legend and just create a text grid they can copy from. Then you don't have to worry about colors, etc.

Comment: @ourmandave thank you for the idea, let me see if i can make it happen